# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when decoding NSValue into b2fixture

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, box2d

Been fighting this problem a while.  I'm using box2D and encoding a b2fixture into an NSValue.  The problem occurs when I decode it using

```
[value getValue:&fixture];
```

This code was working fine in 2012 on my old mac, but seems somewhere in the last 4 years something happened in the matrix !

Here's the relevant code which encodes and decodes:

```
vertGrid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger) xUnits];
for (int x = 0; x <= xUnits; x++) {
    b2Fixture *fixture = ... (not relevant)
    NSValue *wrappedValue = [NSValue value:&fixture withObjCType:@encode(struct b2Fixture)];
    [vertGrid addObject:wrappedValue];


}

//test I can unwrap the vertGrid
for (NSValue *value in vertGrid) {
    b2Fixture *fixture;
    [value getValue:&fixture];
    NSLog(@"yo yo yo");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was working, then by pure chance. Instead of wrapping the content, you were accidentally copying pointers. Changes in memory management and memory alignment likely "break" it now (32-bit vs. 64-bit?).

Anyways, both your wrapping and unwrapping are wrong as both have an additional (incorrect) indirection. Let's start with wrapping the value. Your code is:

```
b2Fixture *fixture = ... (not relevant)
NSValue *wrappedValue = [NSValue value:&fixture withObjCType:@encode(struct b2Fixture)];
```

The documentation of [`-[NSValue value:withObjCType:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/value:withObjCType:) provides the necessary infos:

> `value`: A pointer to data to be stored in the new value object.

Since you want the data to be stored, so you need to pass a `struct b2Fixture *` as the method will then read the data from that memory location, but you're passing a `struct b2Fixture **`. So the wrong data will be copied (the *pointer* instead of the *data*).

Here's another hint at how this method actually works:

> This method has the same effect as `valueWithBytes:objCType:` and may be deprecated in a future release. You should use `valueWithBytes:objCType:` instead.

In other words: the method copies the content, not the pointer to the content. The method name doesn't make that clear which is why the use of `valueWithBytes:objCType:` is a better choice.

So your call to wrap the value must be:

```
NSValue *wrappedValue = [NSValue value:fixture withObjCType:@encode(struct b2Fixture)];
```

(Note the missing `&`).

Next, unwrapping. You have:

```
b2Fixture *fixture;
[value getValue:&fixture];
```

Again, let's look at the [documentation of `-[NSValue getValue:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/getValue:), it says:

> `buffer`: A buffer into which to copy the value. The buffer must be large enough to hold the value

This means you need to allocate the storage. You have two options here: allocate on the stock or on the heap.

```
// Allocate on the stack:
b2Fixture fixture;
[value getValue:&fixture];

// Allocate on the heap:
b2Fixture *fixture = malloc(sizeof(b2Fixture));
[value getValue:fixture]; // No "&"!
...
free(fixture);
```

**Update after comment:**

Since you seem to be trying to wrap a C++ object, you need to things differently. There are two ways I see to solve this:

- Enhance the object so it provides a binary representation and serialize that. Add a constructor that can deserialize the binary representation.
- Use [`+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithPointer:) and [`-[NSValue pointerValue]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/pointerValue). This assumes the object lives on the heap and will make memory management more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately, on the unwrapping. b2Fixture's default constructor is protected, so this fails:

    b2Fixture fixture;

Allocating on the heap also fails 

    b2Fixture *fixture = malloc(sizeof(b2Fixture));
            [value getValue:fixture]; // No "&"!
            free(fixture);

with the error
Cannot initialize a variable with type 'b2Fixture *' with an rvalue of type 'void*'

Comment: Wait… `b2Fixture fixture = malloc(sizeof(b2Fixture));` can't work, it should be `b2Fixture *fixture = malloc(sizeof(b2Fixture));` (note the `*`).

Comment: For the updated comment, I don't want to modify the class - it's from a 3rd party library - would break on updates

Comment: For the malloc update, that then gives error: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'b2Fixture *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'

Comment: Note, the 3rd party library is box2D

Comment: You probably need to go the `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]` route, then. In effect, you already did so before by accident (as I explained in the answer). You might want to think about memory management once more regarding your fixture objects (who is releasing them, when, how does it know it's safe to do so?).

Comment: In making the b2Fixture constructor public, I can make the code run without crashing, however it's now creating a new instance of the b2Fixture - I don't want that - I need to serialise and deserialise the same instance.  I need to modify the existing instance, not a copy.

Comment: I already told you how do fix that: `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]` and take care of your memory management.

Comment: That works, thank you.   Basically using   `NSValue *wrappedValue =  [NSValue valueWithPointer:&fixture ]`    instead of    `NSValue *wrappedValue = [NSValue value:&fixture withObjCType:@encode(struct b2Fixture)]`